# Admob Interstitial show before game start

Tags: android, interstitial

I want to add an interstitial ad on my game just before the game starts.

When you run the app, you have 3 diferent game modes so when you select one, the game starts on that mode. The idea is to show the interstitial after you press the button, just before the game starts.

I have followed the guide on the android developers page, [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial), but this doesn't fit exactly what I need. I have modified a bit to fit with my code, but the interstitial is not shown before starting the game, it is shown when you finish the game and returning to mainActivity.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn1Player = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.OnePlayerImgBtn);
    btnVersus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.VersusImgBtn);
    btnLocalMultiP = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.LCLMultiPlayerImgBtn);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_intersticial_1_id));
    requestNewInterstitial();


    btn1Player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayInterstitial();
            startGame(false,true,MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    });
    btnVersus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayInterstitial();
            startGame(false,true,MODE_VERSUS);
        }
    });
    btnLocalMultiP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayInterstitial();
            startGame(true,true,MODE_LOCALMULTI);
        }
    });

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    });
}



private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}


public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you make an exception on the first run of the activity. Besides a virus or a crash there is no better way to anger your user than to show them an ad before they have even seen the gameplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String singlemode ="Off";
String versus ="Off";
String multi ="Off";

btn1Player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displayInterstitial();
        String singlemode ="On";
    }
});
btnVersus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displayInterstitial();
         String versus ="On";
    }
});
btnLocalMultiP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displayInterstitial();
        String multi="On";
    }
});

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {

if singlemode.equals("On");
{startGame(false,true,MODE_SINGLE);}

if versus.equals("On");
{startGame(false,true,MODE_VERSUS);}

if multimode.equals("On");
{startGame(true,true,MODE_LOCALMULTI);}
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have had to make some modifications to your code to make it work properly, what this is what I needed!

Comment: I wanted to use switch but forgot how. But, you got it working! Good for you. Hope your game is a success.